# How to get laptop docking station serial number programmatically?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, docking-station, wmi, wmic

Is there are a way to get laptop docking station serial number programmatically? I assume it should be accessible via WMI, specifically via Win32_SystemEnclosure class but unable to come up with working query to retrieve it so far?
Specifically I'm trying to do this on Lenovo laptop, but I assume there should be generic method of doing this.

Comment: I may be wrong, but `wmic systemenclosure get SerialNumber`? This would require `ChassisTypes={12}`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394474(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes they say so, but I was not able to retrieve it - maybe my query was wrong or I don't know what else it could be...